# KeyListener refuses to work after implementing it, adding keylistener to an object, and implementing methods

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

I have this main class below that creates a simple JFrame and an extension of the JPanel class called Screen, which is a private inner class that implements KeyListener. I have the constructor for screen add a KeyListener to the object with itself as the parameter. No matter what I try however, it refuses to call the KeyListener methods when I give it input.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main{

    private JFrame window;
    private Screen screen;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Main driver = new Main();

    }

    public Main(){

        window = new JFrame();
        screen = new Screen();
        window.add(screen);
        window.setSize(500, 500);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

    private class Screen extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

        public Screen(){
            this.addKeyListener(this);
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("input received");
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("input received");
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

        }

    }
}
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a very common problem which revolves around how `KeyListener` works.

`KeyListener` only generates key events when the component it is registered to is focusable AND has key board focus.  Before you race of and try and make your `JPanel` focusable, which will only result in it working seemingly randomly, you should use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, which was designed to help solve this problem (with `KeyListener`)